# Unable to connect to sharedfax error

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2000, windows-sbs, fax

EDITED:

I'm running Windows SmallBusinessServer 2000 on a machine with a 56k modem for sending outgoing faxes via the Microsoft Shared Fax Service. I also have a Windows 2003 Enterprise server running terminal services. In the 2003's printers, "sharedfax", is added as a network printer. It shows "unable to connect status", and when right-clicking to edit/view properties, it gives you an error saying "the spool service is not running and you cannot view properties." The spooler service is, however, running on the 2003 server for a fact because I can view all of the local printer properties. On the 2000 server, I show the Microsoft Shared Fax Service AND Print Spooler as started.

Here's the tricky part, I can add the shared fax printer on a locally onto Windows XP machiens (that actually use RDP to connect to the server running terminal services) and it shows ready status sends faxes! They show up in the Fax Console Manager on the 2000 server and send successfully. I've tried this on several different computers and it works every time. Is there a glitch in my 2003 server?

Comment: *Deleted printer from 2003 server and re-added, now stuck in "Opening" status. The fax wizard will come up and let you enter in all info but it never gets transmitted to the shared fax console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using a different server.